# Settings imageview to phone wallpaper

Tags: android, gallery, wallpaper

guys working with Android Gallery and just got it working, however I'm trying to figure out how to get the selected image in the gallery to be set as the phone's wallpaper by the click of a button. Any help is appreciated. Here's the code;

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.gallery);

    imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
    imgView.setBackgroundResource(Imgid[0]);

    gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.examplegallery);
    gallery.setAdapter(new AddImgAdp(this));

    gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position,
                long id) {
            imgView.setBackgroundResource(Imgid[position]);
        }
    });

}

Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });


public class AddImgAdp extends BaseAdapter {
    int GalItemBg;
    private Context cont;

    public AddImgAdp(Context c) {
        cont = c;
        TypedArray typArray = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.GalleryTheme);
        GalItemBg = typArray.getResourceId(
                R.styleable.GalleryTheme_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
        typArray.recycle();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return Imgid.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imgView = new ImageView(cont);

        imgView.setImageResource(Imgid[position]);
        imgView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(80, 70));
        imgView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        imgView.setBackgroundResource(GalItemBg);

        return imgView;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the wallpaper manager:

```
try {
    // Set background from a resource
    WallpaperManager.getInstance(this).setResource(R.drawable.bg);
    // or set background from a bitmap
    WallpaperManager.getInstance(this).setBitmap(mBitmap);

} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Will need this permission in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
```

Comment: Thanks, its working but having trouble getting the selected item in the gallery